# Adding to a many to many relationship table produces duplicate values in db

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, database, entity-framework

I have three tables zRequest, zFacility and a table for a many to many relationship between the two with just the id's of each. My aim is to add a request with many facilities. But whenever I add a new request with some facilities, it adds the selected facilities to zFacility as well as adding to the relationship table.

This is the relevant code in the controller:

```
foreach (var facility in Facilities)
{
    var facName = facility.Replace(".", " ");
    var facQry = from fac in db.zFacilities where fac.FacilityName == facName select fac;
    var facList = facQry.ToList();
    var item = new zFacility();
    item.FacilityId = facList.FirstOrDefault().FacilityId;
    item.FacilityName = facList.FirstOrDefault().FacilityName;
    //db.zFacility.Attach(item);
    zrequest.zFacility.Add(item);
}
zrequestRepository.InsertOrUpdate(zrequest);
zrequestRepository.Save();
```

I have done some research and tried attaching each facility to the database via the commented line but this gave me another error because another entity of the same type already has the same primary key value

This is the code from zRequestRepository:

```
public void InsertOrUpdate(zRequest zrequest)
    {
        if (zrequest.RequestId == default(int)) {
            // New entity
            context.zRequests.Add(zrequest);
        } else {
            // Existing entity
            context.Entry(zrequest).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
        }
    }
```

What can I do to fix this? Let me know if I need to provide more information...

Edit, providing the relevant models as requested.
zFacility:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public partial class zFacility
{
    public zFacility()
    {
        this.zRequest = new HashSet<zRequest>();
        this.zRoom = new HashSet<zRoom>();
    }

    public short FacilityId { get; set; }
    public string FacilityName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<zRequest> zRequest { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<zRoom> zRoom { get; set; }
}
```

zRequest:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public partial class zRequest
{
    public zRequest()
    {
        this.zFacility = new HashSet<zFacility>();
        this.zRoom = new HashSet<zRoom>();
    }

    public int RequestId { get; set; }
    public string ModCode { get; set; }
    public short StatusId { get; set; }
    public int WeekId { get; set; }
    public short DayId { get; set; }
    public short PeriodId { get; set; }
    public short SessionLength { get; set; }
    public short Semester { get; set; }
    public short RoundNo { get; set; }
    public string SpecialRequirement { get; set; }
    public short UserId { get; set; }

    public virtual zDay zDay { get; set; }
    public virtual zPeriod zPeriod { get; set; }
    public virtual zRound zRound { get; set; }
    public virtual zStatus zStatus { get; set; }
    public virtual zWeek zWeek { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<zFacility> zFacility { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<zRoom> zRoom { get; set; }
    public virtual zUser zUser { get; set; }
}
```

These were both generated via a database-first.

Comment: can you post your models?

Comment: @Alundrathedreamwalker, these have been added to the original post.

Comment: where do your facilities in foreach (var facility in Facilities) do come from? Are you sure they are from the same object context?

Comment: Facilities is an array of strings containing the FacilityName's of the selected facilities. This is obtained from the view. I'm not sure what you mean by "the same object context"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EF by default assume that  the selected facilities (**zFacility)**  are new and insert them into the database.

To avoid that , you will need to change the state  to `Unchanged` for **zFacility**

Something like this

```
public void InsertOrUpdate(zRequest zrequest)
    {
        if (zrequest.RequestId == default(int)) {
        context.zFacility.Attach(zrequest); // state Unchanged for zFacility  
        // New entity
       context.zRequests.Add(zrequest);
            } else {
            // Existing entity
            context.Entry(zrequest).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think this one helped most to fix the problem i was having. I had to modify your code slightly as `context.zRequests.Add()` only accepts objects of type zFacility so i looped though the facilities in zrequest and attached them one by one which worked.

Answer (score 0):

What you'll need to do is to select zFactories objects from DB instead of creating new object for each one of them because that makes EF think that you want to create completely new record.

So:
Select zFactories
Add them to the zRequest.zFacility (if they're not already there)
Save

Answer (score 0):

It's a little hard to answer this question as there's some holes in your code. Based on usage, I'm assuming that `Facilities` is an enumerable of strings, and is created from the selected items in your post data.

I'm not sure why you're creating a new `zFacility` instead of using the one that you've already pulled from the database. Doing it the way you are, you're also introducing the possibility of null reference exceptions if there's no matching facility.

Anyways, I would change the code you have to:

```
// This is so you can run a single minimal query to select
// all the facilities you'll be working with
var facNames = Facilities.Select(m => m.Replace(".", " "));
var facList = db.zFacilities.Where(m => facNames.Contains(m.FacilityName)).ToList();

// Now add all facilities not currently attached
facList.Where(m => !zrequest.zFacility.Contains(m)).ToList()
    .ForEach(m => zrequest.zFacility.Add(m));
```

You probably will also need to remove items that have been deselected. The easiest way to do that is to do the last bit of code in reverse:

```
zrequest.zFacility.Where(m => !facList.Contains(m)).ToList()
    .ForEach(m => zrequest.zFacility.Remove(m));
```

**EDIT**

Actually, a more succinct way to remove deselected items would be:

```
zrequest.zFacility.RemoveAll(m => !factList.Contains(m));
```

Comment: I'm planning on using this code to make improve my approach and make it more efficient but i don't understand all of it... could you explain the last two lines of this?